# django save instance between parent and child model class

Tags: django, inheritance, model

I came across this problem on form save the data needs to be persisted somewhere then go through a payment process then on success retrieve the data and save to the proper model.

I have seen this done using session, but with some hacky way to persist file uploads when `commit=False` and it doesn't seem very pythonic

I am thinking if I have a model class A, and have a child class extending A, such as A_Temp

```
class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_lenght=25)
  image = models.ImageField()

class A_Temp(A):
  pass

class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = A_Temp
```

On model form (A_Temp) save, it stores to A_Temp, and when payment successful, it move the instance to the parent model class A.

Here are the questions:

1. Has anyone done this before?
2. How to properly move an instance of a child model class to the parent model class?

Edit:

There are other different ways to do it, such as adding extra fields to the table, yes I would've done that if I am using PHP without a ORM framework, but since the ORM is pretty decent in django, I thought that I might trial something different.

Since I am asking here, means I am not convinced myself about this approach as well. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'm assuming the payment process needs to happen outside of the normal django request/response cycle?

Comment: Is is feasible to add an additional field to Class A and update it instead of shuffling back and forth between A and A_Temp?

Comment: That's the other way I initially thought as well.

Comment: The reason I am trying an alternative to adding a field is when we have extra field to signal the record, the table potentially can contain useless records, in big data scale, will need to create indexes to maintain performance and clean ups. On the other hand the temp model in this case perform as a sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the question comments, adding an extra field to your model containing payment state may be the easiest approach.  Conceptually it's the same object, it's just that the state changes once payment has been made.  As you've indicated, you will need logic to purge out items from your database which never proceed through the required states such as payment.  This may involve adding both a `payment_state` and `state_change_time` field to your model which indicates when the state last changed.  If the state is `PAYMENT_PENDING` for for too long, that record could be purged.

If you take the approach that unpaid items are stored in a different table as you've suggested, you still have to manage that table to determine when it's safe to delete items.  For example, if a payment is never processed, when will you delete record from the `A_temp` table?  Also, having a separate table means that you really only have two states possible, paid and unpaid as determine by the table in which the record occurs.  Having a single table with a `payment_state` may be more flexible in that it allows you to extend the state as required.  eg. Let's say you decide you need the payment states `ITEM_SUBMITTED`, `AWAITING_PAYMENT`, `PAYMENT_ACCEPTED`, `PAYMENT_REJECTED`.  This could all be implemented with a single `state` field.  If this was implemented as you've described, you'd need a separate table for each state.

Having said all that, if you're still set on having a separate table structure, you can create a function which will copy the values from an instance of `A_temp` to `A`.  Something like the following may work, but any relationship type fields such as `ForeignKey` are likely to require special attention.

```
def copy_A_temp_to_A(a, a_temp):
    for field_name in a._meta.fields:
        value = getattr(a, field_name)
        setattr(a_temp, field_name, value)
```

When you need to do the move from `A_temp` to `A`, you'd have to instantiate an `A` instance, then call  the copy function, `save` the instance and delete the `A_temp` instance from the database.

Comment: thank you for the lengthy answer, yes I was aware that I need to purge the temp table as well. The idea may look stupid, reason I asked here is because I want to have the A table as clean as possible, as for different states, extra field can be added to A_Temp model as well. I guess creating database views that segment the listings can be another option for having extra fields in the same model.

Comment: Database views could be one way of solving the 'clean' problem, but this will have its own issues. eg Django doesn't have native support for database views and so cannot create the views during unit testing.  And not all database backends support db views, eg sqlite.  Still, it's possible to do this (I've used this approach too).  Your db view models could set `class Meta: managed=False db_table=<name_of_main_table>`.

Comment: It may also be useful to implement a custom manager which only returns paid items.  eg instead of `A.objects.all()`, use `A.paid_objects.all()`.  Or, override the `objects` default manager to only return paid instances.

Comment: This is lengthy method